# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'bookpage'. Did you forget to specify values ['isbn']?

Tags: python, html, redirect, flask

Please tell me how I can redirect to bookpage when my function is;

```
@app.route("/bookpage/<string:isbn>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def bookpage(isbn):
```

I tried to do following;

```
  return redirect(url_for('bookpage'))
```

I get  this error;

`werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'bookpage'. Did you forget to specify values ['isbn']?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `bookpage(isbn)` without passing an argument.

Pass the `isbn` value like this `return redirect(url_for('bookpage', isbn=123))`.